# How to throw a custom AccessDenied exception in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

The `AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor` has this method that unfortunately makes it really hard to create a custom exception that contains the required information about the required role:

```
private void attemptAuthorization(MethodInvocation mi) {
        this.logger.debug(LogMessage.of(() -> "Authorizing method invocation " + mi));
        AuthorizationDecision decision = this.authorizationManager.check(this.authentication, mi);
        this.eventPublisher.publishAuthorizationEvent(this.authentication, mi, decision);
        if (decision != null && !decision.isGranted()) {
            this.logger.debug(LogMessage.of(() -> "Failed to authorize " + mi + " with authorization manager "
                    + this.authorizationManager + " and decision " + decision));
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Access Denied");
        }
        this.logger.debug(LogMessage.of(() -> "Authorized method invocation " + mi));
    }
```

I would like to use as little custom code as possible, but I still need to keep the ability to tell the user which role was missing and not just "access denied".

Is there a way that we could add a customizer for this?

Comment: This requirement makes no sense. The user can't change its role. Only administrators can change roles. So the information is useless for regular users. But it is a security issue, because the application exposes security information.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. I can tell you it makes sense in our scenario. When it comes to exposing security information, this is always a balance, and letting the user know that you need a certain role to be allowed to perform it is an acceptable one to make (again in our scenario).

Comment: My point is, that Spring Security is built on security best practices, so I wouldn't expect support to easy break these best practices. Maybe I'm wrong, we will see if someone answers your question with an easy solution.

Comment: telling a user which role is missing is aiding people with malicious intents in their endeavors. I too agree, that its very bad practice to give out any type of security information that aids.

Comment: Look, I do not claim that this is not a deviation from the perfect path, but sometimes you have to deal with real-life scenarios. Telling an authenticated user behind (sometimes several) layers of infrastructure security what role they will need to perform a task is useful so they can ask their manager to elevate their privileges. The API docs already mention what role and ACL permissions you are required to hold to perform a certain operation. There is really not any new information exposed other than making your API easier to reason with and debug. Could even have this as a staging/test only